spawn turtle at specific location in turtlesim
I am trying to spawn turtle bot at specific location using launch file. I am able to spawn robot successfully at default location using:
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='turtlesim',
            namespace='turtlesim1',
            executable='turtlesim_node',
            name='sim'
        )
    ])

But unable to spawn at a specific location using:
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([ 
        Node(
            package='turtlesim',
            namespace='turtlesim1',
            executable='turtlesim_node',
            name='sim',
            arguments=['-x', '2' , '-y', '2' , '-t', '2'],
        )
    ])

I have gone through the source code of turtlesim but I'm unable to find an easy way to pass arguments.

Does it need to spawn right away at the right location, or could you use the service calls /kill and /spawn to kill the default turtle and then spawn a new one?

where does it spawn?

@ChristianFritz I want it to spawn directly at the desired location. /kill and /spawn will be an additional overhead.

@jsotola at the center (5.----, 5.----)
